# Replace part of a classname with a value of a button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, css-selectors

I am trying to create a dynamic form that can replace just a part of a class name on link click. For example, all inputs have a class name with the ending _maincss. On click it should find all of these classes and replace them with the value of the clicked button to _secondcss.

Is that possible? The following code might be not the best solution and anyway it's not working well.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#mainCSS').on('click', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.input-row'),
      type = $row.data('type'),
      selector = $row.data('selector');

    $("span, input").removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)_maincss\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-row" data-type="maincss" data-selector="maincss">
  <a id="mainCSS" href="#" class="maincss" value="_maincss">Click here</a><br>
  <a id="secondCSS" href="#" class="secondcss" value="_secondcss">Click here</a><br>
  <a id="thirdCSS" href="#" class="thirdcss" value="_thirdcss">Click here</a><br>
  <input type="text" id="bgcolorMaincss" class="bgcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="textcolorMaincss" class="textcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="linkcolorMaincss" class="linkcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of 'value of the clicked button to _secondcss'? I understood as replace the value with _secondcss?

Comment: @Ajay2707, yes it should replace e.g textcolor_maincss to textcolor_secondclass

Comment: sorry did not understand, what happened when first button click, second button and third button click, give the objects list and value to be updated on those objects

Comment: Just see my answer, is this helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Based on the comments from you I have updated the code so that it now attaches a function to all links and gets the data-value onClick, it then loops all inputs, gets the current data-type from the parent div as the class name to use in the replace function and uses the data-value of the link to do a string replace for each input class.

```js
function updateClassName(replaceStr) {
  const parent = document.querySelector('.input-row')
  const parentType = parent.dataset.type
  
  const els = document.querySelectorAll('input')
  els.forEach(el => {
    const currClass = el.className
    const newClass = currClass.replace(parentType, replaceStr)
    el.classList = newClass
    parent.dataset.type = replaceStr
  })
}

const links = document.querySelectorAll('a')

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click',
    (e) => {
      const replaceStr = e.target.id.toLowerCase()
      console.log(replaceStr)
      updateClassName(replaceStr)
     }
   )
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-row" data-type="maincss">
  <a id="mainCSS" href="#" class="maincss" data-value="_maincss">Click here</a><br>
  <a id="secondCSS" href="#" class="secondcss" data-value="_secondcss">Click here</a><br>
  <a id="thirdCSS" href="#" class="thirdcss" data-value="_thirdcss">Click here</a><br>
  <input type="text" id="bgcolorMaincss" class="bgcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="textcolorMaincss" class="textcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="linkcolorMaincss" class="linkcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" class="another-link_maincss testclass">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my fault i didnt explained this well.. your code is doing halfway good the only thing is missing to keep the beginning of each class..e.g when first button clicked it should change inputs classes from bgcolor_maincss / textcolor_maincss / linkcolor_maincss to following: bgcolor_secondcss / textcolor_secondcss / linkcolor_secondcss ... i need justto change part of the classname which is after the "_"

Comment: His code looks to do exactly that,  just need to update this line to add the `_`: el.classList.add(` ${classArr[0]}_${replaceStr} `)

Comment: yes it looks better but what i need is each time a button clicked it takes its data-value und update the class name of the inputs.. tried following but not sure its right what i am doing: https://jsfiddle.net/qvf53smu/

Comment: YES! its great now just one small issue when the input has more than one class name, the class doesn't change! see text class input no change: https://jsfiddle.net/qvf53smu/1/

Comment: Ok in that case it probably needs to take a slightly different approach where you get the class list as string then use replace to switch the part of the string you want to change then remove the current classes and set the new string as the class

Comment: Ok I've taken a completely different approach with the updated code above where I use and update the wrapping parent data-type as a placeholder for the current class substring to replace. See what you think.

Comment: YES! Awesome work Jon. It's working now like a charm. Thanks a lot for your time and effort for solving the issue.

Comment: No worries @Nash I had fun solving this challenge :)

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the headache by adding an extra class to the elements you would like to manipulate.

```js
function switchClass(callee){
const prefix_classes = ['bgcolor','textcolor','linkcolor'];
//add extra class(dynamic) to elements you want to manipulate then retrieve by className
var dynamic_class_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic");

for(var i = 0; i < dynamic_class_elements.length; i++)
{ 
var dynamic_element = dynamic_class_elements.item(i);
   var current_classes = dynamic_element.className;
   var current_prefix = ''; 
   
for (var index = 0; index < prefix_classes.length; index++) { 
   if(current_classes.indexOf(prefix_classes[index]) !== -1){ 
   //element class contains one of the predefined prefix
   //so we keep track the value
   current_prefix = prefix_classes[index];
   break;
   } 
} 

//replace old element classes with new ones
   var new_class = current_prefix + callee.getAttribute('data-value');
   dynamic_element.className = new_class + ' dynamic'; 
   dynamic_element.value = dynamic_element.className;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-row" data-type="maincss" data-selector="maincss">
  <a id="mainCSS" href="#" class="maincss" data-value="_maincss" onclick="switchClass(this)">Click here</a><br>
  <a id="secondCSS" href="#" class="secondcss" data-value="_secondcss" onclick="switchClass(this)">Click here</a><br>
  <a id="thirdCSS" href="#" class="thirdcss" data-value="_thirdcss" onclick="switchClass(this)">Click here</a><br>
  <input type="text" id="bgcolorMaincss" class="bgcolor_maincss dynamic" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="textcolorMaincss" class="textcolor_maincss dynamic" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="linkcolorMaincss" class="linkcolor_maincss dynamic" value=""><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: switchClass is not defined for some reason

Comment: Did you add the js script to your page?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: Initially did not understand clearly, after some modification based on the link its works
[jQuery replace strings in many classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582034/jquery-replace-strings-in-many-classes)

https://www.anujgakhar.com/2009/04/08/using-jquery-to-change-part-of-the-classname-attribute/

You just need some modification in your jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.maincss').on('click', function() {
        setClasses(this,'maincss')
  });
  $('.secondcss').on('click', function() {
        setClasses(this,'secondcss')
  });
  $('.thirdcss').on('click', function() {
        setClasses(this,'thirdcss')
  });
  
  function setClasses(control, classname)
  {
    $("input").each(function(index ) {      
        $(this).attr ("class",this.className.replace(/maincss/ig,classname).replace(/secondcss/ig,classname).replace(/thirdcss/ig,classname));
        $(this).val(classname);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-row" data-type="maincss" data-selector="maincss">
  <a id="mainCSS" href="#" class="maincss" value="_maincss">Click here</a><br>
  <a id="secondCSS" href="#" class="secondcss" value="_secondcss">Click here</a><br>
  <a id="thirdCSS" href="#" class="thirdcss" value="_thirdcss">Click here</a><br>
  <input type="text" id="bgcolorMaincss" class="bgcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="textcolorMaincss" class="textcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" id="linkcolorMaincss" class="linkcolor_maincss" value=""><br>
</div>
```

Comment: It should just replace the input classname. For example from linkcolor_maincss to linkcolor_secondcss